# p:command button works only once, and works again only if page is refreshed

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml, commandbutton

dears,

My issue is that I have a page that has many command buttons, and the issue is that once a button is clicked and an action is invoked the other command buttons don't work again, even the one I clicked, it doesn't work anymore, it's like only one action is possible per refresh! when I refresh the page again the issue starts over.

I read on the internet that setting ajax to false would fix it but it messed up my page.

sample of one of my buttons:

```
<p:commandButton
  process="@this, name, selectedvalues"
  update="@form, myTable" value="ADD"
  action="#{ManageBean.add()}" oncomplete="PF('Dlg').close();">
</p:commandButton>
```

I use primefaces, and JSF ..

Comment: Please don't post 'samples', post a [mcve]. Setting ajax to false is nit a solution but at most a bad workaround.

Comment: my code is too long that why I posted the command button code. maybe it has something to do with it @Kukeltje

Comment: An [mcve] is abput reducing to the bare minimum that still produces the problem. It os a fundamental part of debugging. Please always do. I suspected the duplicate too but wanted to be sure.

Comment: @Kukeltje duplicate of what?

Comment: Duplicate of the Q/A in the link you see at the top of your question